# How to make object references available in Node modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reference, module

I have an Express.js web app. In the main `app.js` file, I `require()` a bunch of third party dependencies. Recently I've started extracting parts of my `app.js` code into separate modules, e.g.

```
// in app.js
var users = require('./modules/users');

// and then e.g.
// users.add(doc);
```

Inside my modules, I sometimes need to use objects that are available in my main `app.js` file and I'm wondering what's the best way to pass references to those object to my modules.

My current approach:

```
// in app.js

// pass needed object references in initialization step
users.init([db, logger]);
```

and

```
// in modules/users.js

var db, logger;

exports.init = function (deps) {
    db = deps[0];
    logger = deps[1];
};
```

Does this approach make sense? Is there a better way to perform this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just use modules! :)

```
// db.js

// create db instance here rather than in app.js

module.exports = db;
```

And

```
// logger.js

// create logger instance here rather than in app.js

module.exports = logger;
```

Then

```
// app.js

var db = require('./db');
```

And

```
// lib/somewhere.js

var db = require('../db');
```

This way you're able to rely on the CommonJS dependency injection system rather than on doing the dependency injection all by yourself (passing references around instead of `require`ing a module into yours).

The reason why this works as expected is that modules are only interpreted once, so if you instantiate everything once as opposed to using a factory function, it just works.

Comment: Only interpreted once? Holy cow, it all makes sense now :) Somehow I thought that each `require()` creates a new instance of the module.

Comment: Probably in order to make all of that have total sense, db module has to have defined Promise of a db connection instance, because otherwise connection can be not ready yet, and each module which use db conn has to resolve the Promise.

Answer (score 2):

You should just be able to `require` modules as normal:

```
// users.js
var db = require('./db');
exports.init = function() {
   // use db in here
};
```

However, sometimes this isn't possible and you will need to explicitly pass in the module. 
One way to do it is to pass in dependencies when you `require` the module:

```
// users.js
module.exports = function(db, logger) {
    return {
        init: function() { /* use db and logger in here */}
    }; 
}

// app.js
var db = ...;
var logger = ...;
var users = require('./users')(db, logger);
users.init();
```

This is the pattern that I personally prefer, I think it's cleaner to pass dependencies into the require than into some init method like you have in your example.

You'll see this done in ExpressJS code quite a lot, for example when we have all our routes in another file and need to pass our `app` instance around:

```
require('./routes')(app);
```

Comment: Yup, that pattern looks nice. So, the entire users.js module is one big function scope and the outside-references are made available as arguments of that scope.

Answer (score 1):

If you need something to be initialized specifically in `app.js` rather than their own module you can export them from `app.js` and then require `app.js`:

```
// app.js
var db = require("db"),
    logger = require("logger");

// do your initialization with db and logger
module.exports = { db: db, logger: logger };
```

and then:

```
// users.js
var db = require("./app").db,
    logger = require("./app").logger;

// use db and logger
```

This works because as @Nico mentioned, modules are interpreted once and `app.js` will not be interpreted each time it is required from elsewhere.